# Twig templates extending

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-3.4, ezplatform

I'm trying to set up a page layout with separate common header and footer, extending from twig templates.

Page layout it's a typical one with some code like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="zxx">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Soccer | Home</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('assets/images/fav.png') }}">

    <!-- CSS BLOCK -->
    {% stylesheets 'assets/css/*' 'assets/css/style.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
</head>
<body class="home-two">

    {% block page_layout_header %} {% endblock %}

    {% block content %} {% endblock %}

    {% block page_layout_footer %} {% endblock %}

    <!-- JS BLOCK -->
    {% javascripts 'assets/js/jquery.min.js'
        'assets/js/rsmenu-main.js'
        'assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js'
        'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'
        'assets/js/jquery.meanmenu.js'
        'assets/js/wow.min.js'
        'assets/js/slick.min.js'
        'assets/js/masonry.js'
        'assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js'
        'assets/js/time-circle.js'
        'assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js'
        'assets/js/main.js' %}
            <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

</body>
</html>
```

I've got another file under (`app\Resources\views\parts\page_layout_header.html.twig`) where I've set a part of the website, extending from `pagelayout.html.twig`.

Finally, root_folder it's under `full/home.html.twig` and it renders a simple template like this:

```
{% extends "pagelayout.html.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Root page</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

In the `ezplatform.yml` I've set the root folder and a line for the header twig.

```
content_view:
    full:
        root_folder:
            template: "full/home.html.twig"
            match:
                Id\Location: 67
    line:
        line_part_header:
            template: "parts/page_layout_header.html.twig"
            match:
                Identifier\ContentType: ['defined_content_type']
```

The issue comes when launching `127.0.0.1:8000` root page and nothing appears to be rendered. Only content from root ez folder is showing without any CSS Style. It seems that extending from twig templates is not working...

EDIT: Going to explain my situation better.

This is partial of `pagelayout.html.twig` which has all CSS, js and block definitions

```
{% stylesheets 'assets/css/*' 'assets/css/style.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}

{% block header %} {% endblock %}

{% block content %} {% endblock %}

{% block footer %} {% endblock %}


<!-- BLOQUE JS -->
{% javascripts 'assets/js/*' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Next, I've got a `page_layout_header.html.twig` which contains a top bar and the main menu.

```
{% extends ':themes/club:pagelayout.html.twig' %}
{% block header %}
<!--Header area start here-->
<header>
    <div class="header-top-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="header-top-left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="mailto:#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ ez_render_field( content, 'web_config_email_contacto' ) }}</a></li>
                            <li><img src="{{ asset('assets/images/logo/flag.jpg') }}" alt="Logo">
                            ......
                            ......
```

And finally, this is the config:

```
home:
    template: "themes/club/full/home/home.html.twig"
    match:
        Id\Location: 2
full_top:
    template: "themes/club/parts/page_layout_header.html.twig"
    match:
        Identifier\ContentType: 'informacion_general'
```

So, when testing `http://127.0.0.1` I cannot see anything more than `{{ ez_render_field(content, 'description') }}`

Comment: Are u trying to modify the block `header` from inside an included file? This is [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330832/twig-can-a-child-template-override-a-block-from-a-file-included-in-the-parent-t/49334962#49334962) in `twig`

Comment: Can you show us your twig ? We need to see how the templates extends and which blocks are extended

Comment: @Med You've got it in my last edition

Answer (score 0):

Extending templates means that child template extends parent template, but it doesn't mean parent template includes child one.

So your both templates (`home.html.twig` and `page_layout_header.html.twig`) extend `pagelayout.html.twig` independently. And they both don't know anything about each other.

I'm not familiar with EzPlatform but it looks like `full` and `line` view types are just different configurations to be chosen by ViewProvider or something like this.

So I decide you should embed reusable parts of html by simply including it like this:

```
{% include 'page_layout_header.html.twig' %}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html

or by rendering it with separate controller like this:

```
{{ render(controller("ez_content:viewAction", {"contentId": 123, "viewType": "line"})) }}
```

https://doc.ezplatform.com/en/2.1/guide/content_rendering/#embedding-content-items