# Modify a parent block from an included file

Tags: twig, symfony4

I'm new to twig and I'm having some problems.

Here is my question:
I have 3 twig templates:

***base.html.twig which I extend in home.html.twig and header / basic.html.twig included in home.html.twig***

```
{#base.html.twig#}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="vw-100">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
     <meta name="robots" content="index"/>
     <meta name="keywords" content="{% block keywords %}{% endblock %}"/>
     <meta name="description" content="{% block description %}{% endblock %}"/>
     <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ asset('assets/images/icon.png') }}"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/dist/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/base.css') }}">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/footer/basic.css') }}">
     {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
     <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/dist/fontawesome.min.js') }}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <body class="vw-100">
     {% block body %}{% endblock %}
     {% include 'footer/basic.html.twig' %}
     <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/dist/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/dist/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/dist/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/base.js') }}"></script>
     {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
 </body>
</html>
```

```
{#home.twig.html#}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block keywords %}{% endblock %}
{% block description %}{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Accueil{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/homePage.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% include 'header/basic.html.twig' with {h1: 'Enterprise Name', text_link: 'Learn More', link: 'link', text: 'some text'}%}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
```

```
{#header/basic.html#}
<header class="vw-100">
    <div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column justify-content-center">
        <main role="main" class="inner cover text-center">
            <h1 class="cover-heading theme-text-color">{{ h1 }}</h1>
            <p class="lead theme-text-color">{{ text }}</p>
            <p class="lead">
                <a href="{{ link }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-light theme-text-color" target="_blank">{{ text_link }}</a>
            </p>
        </main>
    </div>
</header>
```

I need to add a link to the stylesheet block from the header/basic.html.twig template like this:

```
{#header/basic.html#}
{% block stylesheets %}
    ...{# home.twig.html content #}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/header/basic.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
<header class="vw-100">
    <div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column justify-content-center">
        <main role="main" class="inner cover text-center">
            <h1 class="cover-heading theme-text-color">{{ h1 }}</h1>
            <p class="lead theme-text-color">{{ text }}</p>
            <p class="lead">
                <a href="{{ link }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-light theme-text-color" target="_blank">{{ text_link }}</a>
            </p>
        </main>
    </div>
</header>
```

I tried a lot of things, but I didn't succeed.
Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding blocks within included Twig templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755818/overriding-blocks-within-included-twig-templates)

Comment: No, I want to do the reverse because in this example it is the base.html.twig file which passes the variable to header.html.twig. While on my side I want to modify the {% stylesheet%} of base.html.twig from header.html.twig

Comment: Not possible, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49334962/446594) why